# I'm using the following code in body section. How can I make it center without using <div align="center"> tag?

Tags: html

```
<div align="center"><a href="https://twitter.com/ambradeibimbi" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="true" data-lang="it">Segui @ambradeibimbi</a>

    <script>
        ! function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
    </script> <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Ambra dei Bimbi" data-lang="it" data-hashtags="ambradeibimbi">Tweet</a>

    <script>
        ! function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
    </script>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Ambra-dei-Bimbi/302029161075?id=302029161075&amp;sk=app_208195102528120" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: Please format your code!

Comment: Always have a indented code.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS, example (first `div`):

```
<div style="margin:auto;width:100%">
```

`margin:auto` aligns the `div` to the center of its parent container. 
You need `width:100%` or else `margin:auto` will not work.

Comment: This only works when the div has a `width` set as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper `<div>` and set the margin to auto for left and right.

Html

```
<div class="center">
{... Your code here... }
</div>
```

CSS

```
.center {
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}
```

You may also need to set the desired width of this element.

Answer (score 0):

Give one class or `id` to `div` then do css:

```
<div class="social">
  content 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.social {
   width: 50%; // what ever width you want you can put
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```